# Best practices for POST/DELETE links on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, w3c, web-standards

I don’t want to use GET method for some destructive links (like deleting an item, remove something…) so I use POST or DELETE actions on my links, with a Javascript AJAX request like this:

```
<a class="js-link" data-method="DELETE" data-confirmation="Are you sure?" data-href="xxx">
```

I don't use `href` because the URL is not available with a GET method (error 405).

My questions are:

- What are the best-practices for these kind of links?
- Is this valid HTML?
- What about users without JS, old browsers?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use a button or `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: not using href attribute is most certainly against web standards

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the appropriate solution here is to use a `<button>` or similar. Since these are not hypertext links that you can [follow](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#following-hyperlinks-2), which can be followed by e.g. search engine crawlers, they should not be represented using the `<a>` hypertext anchor element.

Note that according to [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element):

> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents.

so your usage of `href`-less `<a>` does not match the standard's definition.